# How to let Vertical ScrollView can left or right Swipe in Maui?

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, maui

In maui,
I try to add a SwipeGestureRecognizer to ScrollView's parent, ScrollView can scroll, but swipe event not be invoked.
I try to  add a SwipeGestureRecognizer to ScrollView, swipe event be invoked, but scrollview can't scroll.

Comment: You can try to customize the Scrollview, rewrite the ontouchevent and dispatchtouchevent methods, and finally order the existing Scrollview to inherit the custom Scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

A easy way to resolve left or right Swipe of scrollview is that you can let child of scrollview add a SwipeGestureRecognizer. It is not good way, but work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar case in which i have a web view that contain a long text "more than the screen length and i need to sclool up and down and also to swipe left and right, i was able to achive that using this elemnts structure, hope this can help.

```
 <ScrollView Grid.Row="1" ZIndex="1"
     HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
     HeightRequest="-1" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
     <WebView x:Name="MyWebView" HeightRequest="-1"     
         BackgroundColor="Transparent">
         <WebView.GestureRecognizers>
             <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Left" 
                 Swiped="OnSwipedLeft"/>
             <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Right" 
                 Swiped="OnSwipedRight"/>
         </WebView.GestureRecognizers>
     </WebView> 
</ScrollView>
```